# RegionPlot3D KnotData

Tags: graphics3d, regions, knots

Is it possible to find or construct a `RegionPlot` out of `KnotData`? My motivation is to `Texture` the knots as per [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236449/circle-packing-in-cone-texture).

After much searching and playing around, I found [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/401983), which frustratingly doesn't give the equations for the `inTinftube` and `onTinftube` functions.

Desired output is something like this (but in 3D):

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**

```
n = 15;
vor = VoronoiMesh[
   RandomPoint[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 π, 2 π}], 
    n], {{0, 2 π}, {0, 2 π}}];
polys = MeshPrimitives[vor, 2];
g = Show[Table[{Red, 
      Disk[x /. Last[#], Abs@First[#]] &@
       NMinimize[SignedRegionDistance[poly][x], 
        x ∈ poly]}, {poly, polys}] // Graphics];
curve3 = KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"];
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[curve3[t], t]];
{tangent, normal, binormal} = basis;
ParametricPlot3D[
 curve3[t] + .6 (Cos[u]*normal + Sin[u]*binormal), {u, 0, 
  2 π}, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Texture[g], 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, t}, {u, 9 t}], 
 ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.3, 3.3}]
```

[image]

**Original**

A starting point.

```
curve3 = KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"];
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[curve3[t], t]];
{tangent, normal, binormal} = basis;
g = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, .5]}, PlotRangePadding -> .5];
ParametricPlot3D[
 curve3[t] + .6 (Cos[u]*normal + Sin[u]*binormal), {u, 0, 
  2 π}, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Texture[g], 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t, u}, {x, y}], 
 ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.3, 3.3}]
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can feed the `BoundaryMeshRegion[]` you can obtain from `KnotData[]` into `RegionPlot3D[]`. For example:

```
trefBMR = KnotData["Trefoil", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
RegionPlot3D[RegionMember[trefBMR, {x, y, z}],
             {x, -7/2, 7/2}, {y, -7/2, 7/2}, {z, -3/2, 3/2},
             BoxRatios -> Automatic, Lighting -> "Neutral",
             Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 35, 
             PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture",
                                                         "WhiteMarble"}]]]]
```

[image: marbled knot]

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Is it possible to vary the thickness of the knot?

Comment: It's a little harder to do, but certainly doable. (You'll have to wait a bit for it, as I am currently evaluating something else.)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
Multicolumn[Graphics3D[{SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[disks]], 
     Tube[BSplineCurve[KnotData[#, "SpaceCurve"] /@ Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 100], 
       SplineClosed -> True], .4]}, 
    Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Medium, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 5}] & /@ 
 {{"PretzelKnot", {5, 3, 2}}, "FigureEight",
  {"TorusKnot", {3, 5}}, {"TorusKnot", {4, 9}}}, 2]
```

**Update:** In versions 12.1+, we can use the directive `SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[img]]` to texturize any surface with `img`:

```
reg = TriangulateMesh[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[]], MaxCellMeasure -> .02];

disks = Graphics[{Red, MeshPrimitives[reg, 2] /. Polygon -> (Apply[Disk] @* Insphere)}];

 Graphics3D[{SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[disks]], 
   KnotData["Trefoil", "ImageData"]}, 
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

We can construct a `Tube` with the desired radius using `KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"]`:

```
Graphics3D[{SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[disks]], 
  Tube[BSplineCurve[KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"] /@ Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 100], 
    SplineClosed -> True], .5]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[disks]]` as the setting for `PlotStyle` in `ParametricPlot3D` in cvgmt's answer:

```
ParametricPlot3D[curve3[t] + .6 (Cos[u] normal + Sin[u] binormal), 
 {u, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[disks]], 
 ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.3, 3.3}, Lighting->"Neutral"]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

We can use the new-in-12.1 directive `HalfToneShading`:

```
Graphics3D[{HalftoneShading[#, Red], KnotData["Trefoil", "ImageData"]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> 250, Boxed -> False, 
    ViewPoint -> {1.5, -1.5, 4.}] & /@ {.3, .5, .7} // Row
```

[image]

Needless to say, this approach is not match for cvgmt's approach in terms of flexibility and beauty of the pictures produced.

To get some flexibility in controlling the density of shapes, we can use the options of `SurfaceAppearance` to define a directive with options:

```
Options[surfaceAppearance] = {"StepCount" -> 1, "Tiling" -> {5, 5}, 
   "FeatureColor" -> Red, "UseScreenSpace" -> 0, "IsTwoTone" -> 1, 
   "LuminanceModifier" -> 0.0, "Shape" -> "Disk"};

surfaceAppearance[opts : OptionsPattern[surfaceAppearance]] := 
 SurfaceAppearance["RampShading", 
  Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts, Options[surfaceAppearance]}, Except["Shape"]], 
  "Arguments" -> {"HalftoneShading", 0.5, Red, OptionValue["Shape"]}, 
  EdgeForm[], Texture["HalftoneShading" <> OptionValue["Shape"]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Graphics3D[{surfaceAppearance[], KnotData["Trefoil", "ImageData"]},
  Lighting -> "Accent", Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1.5, -1.5, 4.}]
```

[image]

Use `surfaceAppearance["Tiling" -> {15, 15}]` to get:

[image]

Use `surfaceAppearance["UseScreenSpace" -> 1, "StepCount" -> 2, "Tiling" -> {7, 7}]` to get:

[image]

Use `surfaceAppearance["Tiling" -> {15, 15}, "Shape"->"Triangle"]` to get:

[image]

Use  `surfaceAppearance["StepCount" -> 3,"Tiling" -> {10,10},"Shape" -> "Hexagon"]` to get:

[image]

Comment: brilliant - thankyou! had no idea this existed :)

Answer (score 5):

```
SliceContourPlot3D[Sin[5 x] Sin[6 y] Sin[4 z], 
 KnotData["Trefoil", "Region"],
 {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
 Contours -> {-1/6, 1/6}, ContourStyle -> None, 
 ContourShading -> {White, Red}, 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 90]
```

[image]