# Graph embedding constrained to a surface?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, graphs-and-networks, mesh, modeling

Have been contemplating it for a while, but did not dare to post as I felt like this must be a major undertaking to implement. Then saw the excellent answers to a recent question [RegionPlot3D KnotData](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/240690/35000) and decided to try anyway.

Given a surface via, say, implicit or parametric equation, and a graph, given, say, as a `Graph` object, is there a way to draw this graph on that surface with, say, analog of the `SpringElectricalEmbedding` or something like that?

As an ultimate goal, one would think of creating programmatically optimal versions of, e. g., this fantastic image

[image]

from "[Patterns on the genus-3 Klein quartic](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Carlo_Sequin/publication/247124890_Patterns_on_the_Genus3_Klein_Quartic/links/0deec529e850c7090c000000.pdf)" by Carlo H. Séquin.

For a specific goal of mine - under [one of the questions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304138/41291) on mathoverflow, there is a gluing scheme

[image]

for a graph on a genus 4 surface which in principle I could concoct but it would be ugly. I wonder if it could be done optimally using elastic string tension modeling possibilities of existing Mathematica functions.