# How does `TextureCoordinateFunction[]` works within `SurfaceAppearance[]`?

Tags: graphics3d

Following up from @kglr 's [answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240859/9923), I'd like to understand how `TextureCoordinateFunction[]` works within `SurfaceAppearance[]`. I'm using

```
g = Graphics[{White, Thickness[.5], Line /@ Table[{{0, y}, {1, y}}, {y, 0, 20}]}, 
Background -> Black, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
Graphics3D[{SurfaceAppearance["TextureShading", Texture[g]], 
Tube[BSplineCurve[KnotData[{3, 1}, "SpaceCurve"] /@ Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 100], 
SplineClosed -> True], 1]}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Medium, 
ViewPoint -> {0.2, 0.2, 3.3}, ViewVertical -> {0, -1, .25}]
```

but the texture doesn't seem to be aligning correctly. It is turning out like this

[image]

rather than this

[image]

I have tried applying the `TextureCoordinateFunction[]` directive inside `SurfaceAppearance[]`, but it doesn't seem to work.