# Custom style arrows

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I want to make arrows with custom styles, as shown below. However, I do not know how to design these in *Mathematica-12.0*. I tried using `Graphics`, `Arrow` and `Arrowheads`, but they produce regular boring arrows.

Does anyone know how to customise these? It would be very helpful if you could at least direct me correctly.

[image] [image] [image]

However, as suggested by @Domen, the [Custom arrow shaft](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11545/84456) question is similar to mine. However, the answer there is not complete. So, my question is justified

Comment: Yes, It's helpful. However, I just want these three specific arrows. Specifically the first and the last one

Comment: It is expected on this site that you first show your own work, trying to code the solution.

Comment: I have reopen this problem. I think it is  valuable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The third arrow.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = {{0, 
    0}, {-.5, .5}, {-.5, .25}, {-1.75, .25}, {-1.75, -.25}, {-.5, \
-.25}, {-.5, -.5}};
poly = BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, 
   Line@Append[#, First@#] &@Range@Length@pts];
conics = 
  Table[ConicHullRegion[{-1.75, h}, {{0, 0}}, {AngleVector[.02], 
     AngleVector[-.02]}], {h, -1, 1, .1}];
range = {{-2, 1}, {-1, 1}};
Graphics[
 RegionIntersection[
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion@conics, range], poly]]
```

[image]

- the second 3D arrow.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {-.5, .5}, {-.5, .25}, {-1.75, .25}, {-1.5, 
    0}, {-1.75, -.25}, {-.5, -.25}, {-.5, -.5}};
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], , 
   RegionProduct[Polygon[pts], Point[{{0.}, {.2}}]]}, 
  Black, {HalftoneShading[.3, Red, "Line"], 
   RegionProduct[RegionBoundary@Polygon[pts], Line[{{0.}, {.2}}]]}}, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Use `RegionPlot3D` to add shading.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {-.5, .5}, {-.5, .25}, {-1.75, .25}, {-1.5, 
    0}, {-1.75, -.25}, {-.5, -.25}, {-.5, -.5}};
side = RegionPlot3D[
   RegionProduct[RegionBoundary@Polygon[pts], Line[{{0.}, {.2}}]], 
   MeshFunctions -> {Normalize@{1, 2, 3} . {#1, #2, #3} &}, 
   Mesh -> 60, MeshStyle -> None, MeshShading -> {Red, Black, Red}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], 
   RegionProduct[Polygon[pts], Point[{{0.}, {.2}}]]}, First@side}, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- `Texture` seems still not so perfect. ( $Version 14.0.0)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = {{0, 0}, {-.5, .5}, {-.5, .25}, {-1.75, .25}, {-1.5, 
    0}, {-1.75, -.25}, {-.5, -.25}, {-.5, -.5}};
side = RegionProduct[Line[Append[#, First@#] &@pts], 
   Line[{{0.}, {.2}}]];
pic = Graphics[{Red, HatchFilling[π/2*.88, 10, 20], 
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]}, Background -> Black, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], 
   RegionProduct[Polygon[pts], Point[{{0.}, {.2}}]]}, Texture[pic], 
  side}, Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- make the sides have the same pattern.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = {{0, 0}, {-.5, .5}, {-.5, .25}, {-1.75, .25}, {-1.5, 
    0}, {-1.75, -.25}, {-.5, -.25}, {-.5, -.5}};
θ = π/3;
h = .2;
mesh[a_, b_] := Module[{e2, poly, e1, normal},
  e2 = {0, 0, 1};
  poly = Polygon[{a, b, b + h*e2, a + h*e2}];
  e1 = Normalize[b - a];
  normal = 
   Normalize[Cross@{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} . {e1, e2}];
  RegionPlot3D[poly, Mesh -> {Range[-10, 10, .02]}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {normal . ({#1, #2, #3}) &}, 
   MeshShading -> {Red, Black}, Boxed -> False]]
Graphics3D[{First /@ 
   mesh @@@ Partition[PadRight[#, 3] & /@ pts, 2, 1, 1], Red, 
  PadRight[#, 3, 0] & /@ pts // Polygon, 
  PadRight[#, 3, h] & /@ pts // Polygon}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you. It looks amazing. Just one more query: is there a way to increase the distance between lines and the thickness of it?

Comment: If you rotate the arrow, the left side(other side) of the arrowhead has a different pattern than the rest of it.

Answer (score 6):

#### 1.

Playing with [`ImageEffect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageEffect.html)

```
ImageEffect[Rasterize @
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    Graphics @ Text @ Style["→", 60], _Text, 
    MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Red, 1 -> None}], 
 {"Jitter", 10}]
```

[image]

Combine multiple effects (`{"Jitter", 20}`, `{"MotionBlur", 30, Pi/6}` and `{"Jitter", 2}`:

```
Fold[ImageEffect, 
 ImagePad[Rasterize @
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    Graphics @ Text @ Style["\[RightArrow]", 72], _Text, 
    MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Red, 1 -> None}], 
  30, White], 
 {{"Jitter", 20},
  {"MotionBlur", 30, Pi/6},
  {"Jitter", 2}}]
```

[image]

#### 2.

With `pts` from [cvgmt's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296867/125), an alternative way to get a 3D arrow using `RegionPlot3D`:

```
RegionPlot3D[Polygon @ Map[Append[0]] @ pts, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 "Extrusion" -> .2, 
 "ExtrusionStyle" -> {Red, 
   SurfaceAppearance["RampShading", "StepCount" -> 1, 
    "Tiling" -> {-20, 1}, Texture["HalftoneShadingLine"]]}, 
 Boxed -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]
```

[image]

Replace `"Tiling" -> {-20, 1}` with `"Tiling" -> {20, 1}` to get

[image]

Use `"Tiling" -> {20, 0}` to get

[image]

***See also:*** [RegionPlot3D KnotData](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/240690/125)

Comment: Thank you @kglr. The first arrow looks really amazing and thank you for showing how to change the patterns in the 2nd arrow.

Comment: Since, I'm on *Mathematica 13.0*, many of the options are not available. :(

Comment: @user444,   these methods work in versions 13.3 and 14.0.